# Finish all activities and restart application in Android

Tags: android

I would like to finish all the activities in an Android app and then restart it from the beginning. Is there an easy way to achieve this without finishing one by one until I come back to the first one?

Comment: What @njzk2 probably meant to say is: It's very unlikely that you would ever need to do this; could you please state your intentions so we can help you solve it in a user-friendly way?

Comment: @njzk2: I have an activity to remove the user account, I want everything to be closed if the user removes his account.

Comment: @njzk2: which was the purpose of your comment?

Comment: the purpose of my comment was to give a little more perspective to your question. There may be several answers depending of your final purpose. In your case, one could be to have test in onResume of each of your activities (which can be factorized in a parent class) to see if the user was removed/changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just clear the task when launching your intent.

```
Intent restartIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
restartIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //Set this flag
startActivity(restartIntent);
finish();
```